# How to validating escaped xml characters in soapui

Tags: soapui

I am using soapui to validate my API's and I have JDBC TestCase in my TestSuite so when I submit JDBC query I am getting XML response but the XML response I am getting has escaped t`enter code here`he XML special characters (< and >).

I want to validate this response using XPath or XQuery but I am having a problem to read the special characters.

I have posted part of my response I wanted to validate below.

```
 <MESSAGE>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
```

Comment: I am sorry the special characters didn't appear on my question but in my response I have a message element and < is represented by &lt; and > by &gt;

<MESSAGE>&lt;S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
  &lt;env:Header/&gt;
  &lt;S:Body&gt;

Comment: To format code properly, select it an press Ctrl-K  (or the "code sample" button in the editor).

Comment: Can you show the problem using a screen shot?